# Copy Special Cells (Validation Cells) several times

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a spreadsheet that I can copy several times with "n" value with the following code:

```
With Range("A8:M14")
    rws = .Rows.Count + 1
    .Resize(rws).Copy Destination:=.Offset(rws).Resize(rws * (n - 1))
End With
```

It works perfectly and copy my range "n" times, BUT in the last colmn I've got special cells containing Validation (Tick Boxes) and that doesn't get copied.

Please help me.

Comment: I assume you are talking about controls which are not contained in a cell, right?

Comment: The cheapest possible solution - I suppose the checkboxes are ActiveX elements. Can you simply exchange them with Form Element and live happily ever after?

Comment: Thanks Vityata. Your input was VERY helpful